# How to gain insight into spotlight index?

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I'd like to get a list of all indexed files and their path that spotlight came across. How would I do that ? mdutil does not seem to be of any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command will list all files indexed by spotlight system:

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '*'"
```

To store the output in a file:

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '*'" > listOfFiles.txt
```